# put picture into database c# webapi asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

i have table for apartments ,villas,chalets, duplex
i need to put for each estate(villa,apartment,chalete) like 5 pictures i have a folder for each table and i don't know how to make the table have 5 pictures in database or the path in controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Try.Models;

namespace Try.DAL.Entity
{
    [Table("Apartments")]
    public class Apartments 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Boolean Garden { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public int St_num { get; set; }
        public Double Price { get; set; }
        public int Floors_numbers { get; set; }
        [MaxLength]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UsersId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UsersId))]

        public Users Users { get; set; }
        public int Propertiesid { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Propertiesid")]
        public Properties Properties { get; set; }
        //public IFormFileCollection ApartmentImages { get; set; }

        

        public string PhotoName { get; set; }
       // public IFormFile PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Apartments> Order_Apartments { get; set; }
      }


    }
}
```

controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Try.DAL.Database;
using Try.DAL.Entity;
using Try.Models;

namespace Try.Controller
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApartmentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DbContainer _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

        public ApartmentsController(DbContainer context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        // GET: api/Apartments
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Apartments>>> GetApartments()
        {
            return await _context.Apartments.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Apartments/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Apartments>> GetApartments(int id)
        {
            var apartments = await _context.Apartments.FindAsync(id);

            if (apartments == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return apartments;
        }

        // PUT: api/Apartments/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutApartments(int id, Apartments apartments)
        {
            if (id != apartments.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(apartments).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ApartmentsExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Apartments
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Apartments>> PostApartments(Apartments apartments)
        {
         

          
                    _context.Apartments.Add(apartments);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return CreatedAtAction("GetApartments", new { id = apartments.Id }, apartments);
                }

        // DELETE: api/Apartments/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteApartments(int id)
        {
            var apartments = await _context.Apartments.FindAsync(id);
            if (apartments == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Apartments.Remove(apartments);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool ApartmentsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Apartments.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }

        private async Task<string> UploadImage(string folderPath, IFormFile file)
        {

            folderPath += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName;

            string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folderPath);

            await file.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));

            return "/" + folderPath;
        }
    }
}
```

now i have a folder with images for each table i don't know how to put like 5 pictures for each table

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't. A relational database is made for structured data but a picture is unstructured data. It is not a good fit functionally speaking. I would store the picture on some centralized disk/storage like an S3 bucket or a UNC or something similar with a structured path that you can recreate from the database values (like an ID for example).

Comment: @Igor - Actually, many relational databases are very good at storing unstructured data.  Oracle, for example, has CLOB column type which is designed for storing exactly such type of data the OP mentions.  If you need transactional support, for example, there are huge advantages to storing the data in the DB itself. You can refer to Tom Kyte's arguments here for this use case: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:1011065100346196442. And here's another link too: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=unstructred-data

Comment: @dcp - It is very much a matter of opinion and also use case. The first link has a very long back/forth discussion under the initial opinion on the matter. Also why I prefaced my comment with Side note and *I* wouldn't (Maybe IMO instead would have been more clear). I do have a feeling that Oracle is not involved though (It is relatively more complex to setup than a localdb or sqlexpress instance which is what the OP is more likely using). Not that sql server can't handle unstructured data (it can with `varbinary(max)`).

Comment: okay how about make a table for photos and put url in ot then what should i do